# Site root translation in css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to get the site root relative translation in the CSS file of an MVC3 app?

In the .cshtml, I can use:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However, in the CSS I need to access content such as:

```
background-image: url('/Content/images/banner.png');
```

I would like to be able to get the root like i can with the @Url.Content so i can do something like this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
background-image: url(@Url.Content("~/Content/images/banner.png"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Urls in css files are relative to the css file - it is not possible to specify the url relative?

If not then you will need to have ASP.NET process the file. You can either add a mapping to make all css files processed by the ASP.NET engine or to rename the css file into a file with with an extension that already is processed by ASP.NET - such as .aspx. You will probably also need a page directive to make it work...

Comment: +1, and there is no *If not ...*. Urls in CSS files should be specified as relative to the location of the CSS file, full stop.

Comment: I was not aware that it was CSS file relative.  That makes a lot more sense.  Thanks.